# Blazor WASM - getting "Authorization failed" although User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns true

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have an account service that implements the `AuthenticationStateProvider`. In the constructor I initialize the state of the current user by looking into local storage for access token. If I find a valid one the initial state would be logged-in and user will be able to use the app. Otherwise the `AuthorizeRouteView` will redirect the user to the login page:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <Forbidden />
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

The login page injects an `AccountService` which implements the `AuthenticationStateProvider`. Login page also subscribes to the `AuthenticationStateChanged` event to redirect the user to home page. On a successful login the state of the app will be updated and the redirect call-back will be called:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    // ...

    AccountService.AuthenticationStateChanged += Redirect;
}

async void Redirect(Task<AuthenticationState> authTask)
{
    var state = await authTask;
    if (state.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Going in...");
        Navigation.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
```

In the console, I see the "Going in..." message but I get the following error:

> Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
> DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEEta.png)

Now the weird thing is that when I refresh the browser I am logged in. I don't know If this is a bug or there is something I'm missing. After logging in I update the state with `NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged`:

```
void UpdateState(ClaimsPrincipal user)
{
    // For debugging
    Console.WriteLine("Updating state: ");
    foreach (var c in user.Claims)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  " + c.Type + ": " + c.Value);
    }
    var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
    NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
}
```

My DI:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AccountService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider, AccountService>();
```

I also tried `NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync())` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61784905/19363672) but it didn't work.

Comment: Changing the services to scoped, solved the problem. This is weird because it says in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#service-lifetime) that: Blazor WebAssembly apps don't currently have a concept of DI scopes. Scoped-registered services behave like Singleton services.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61784905/19363672)):

```
NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
```

and

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AccountService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<AccountService>());
```