# How to keep actual AuthenticationState in C# Blazor Server App?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` service that stores credentials in localStorage.

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

`AuthStateProvider.cs` (`CustomAuthStateProvider`):

Save to storage:

```
public async Task UpdateAuthenticationState(string jwtToken = null) 
{
    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = Claims.Anonymous;

    if (jwtToken != null) 
    {
        SecurityToken securityToken;
        var claims = JwtHandler.ValidateToken(jwtToken, await _tokenValidator.GetValidationParameters(), out securityToken);

        if (securityToken != null && claims != null) 
        {
            claimsPrincipal = claims;
            await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("AuthToken", jwtToken);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        await _localStorage.RemoveItemAsync("AuthToken");
    }

    NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
}
```

Get from storage:

```
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync() {
        try {
            //await Task.Delay(5000);
            var userSessionStorageResult = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("AuthToken");
            if (userSessionStorageResult != null) {
                SecurityToken securityToken;
                var claims = JwtHandler.ValidateToken(userSessionStorageResult, await _tokenValidator.GetValidationParameters(), out securityToken);
                if (securityToken != null && claims != null)
                    return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claims));
            }
        } catch { }

        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(Claims.Anonymous)));
        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(Claims.Anonymous));

    }
```

`App.razor`:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

`Index.razor` (this page):

```
@page "/"
@attribute [Authorize]

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<Button Color="ButtonColor.Primary" @onclick="OnlyAuthButton">OnlyAuth</Button>

@code{
    [Inject] protected ToastService ToastService { get; set; }

    private async Task OnlyAuthButton() {
        ToastService.Notify(new ToastMessage(ToastType.Danger, Loc["Some error occured"]));
    }
}
```

When I update authentication state, it performs `NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged` that rerenders the Blazor components and all works good.

[Authenticated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI2TH.png)

But when I delete token from local storage manually and click button, Blazor app does not check authentication state and works like I'm authorized until I reload page.

[Unauthenticated by deleting token from local storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svfYT.png)

[After reloading by F5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oNE3.png)

Is there any common solutions such as middleware for actions on Razor Components with SignalR that can validate authentication state. For example I click button => Blazor checks authentication => Blazor execute ButtonClick handler method. Of course I can retrieve AuthState in begin of handler but it's mean that I need to place this action in `each` handler in application and this sounds not good.

PS: it's necessary to use local storage instead cookie because I need crosstab application

Comment: It's a web application. [Use COOKIE authentication](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/asp-net-core-angular-xsrf-62c3833fd1fe)

Comment: **Typo** alert - it's **authentication** - not "authentification" - there's no "fi" in that word...

Comment: I see no code where you are calling `_localStorage.GetItemAsync`, so have no idea how you are retrieving the token.  Code please!

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61783060/blazornotifyauthenticationstatechanged-doesnt-update-authorized-based-elements